# If every function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous for a non-empty topological space $X$ then does $X$ have the discrete topology ?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $X$ be a non-empty topological space such that every function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous , then is every subset of $X$ open ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick any $x\in X$ and define $f:X\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $y=x$,}\\0&\text{if $y\in X$, $y\neq x$.}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, the interval $(1/2,3/2)$ is open in $\mathbb R$, so $\{x\}=f^{-1}((1/2,3/2))$ is open in $X$, since $f$ is continuous by assumption. Therefore, every singleton in $X$ is open, so the topology in question must be the discrete one.

Answer (score 4):

Given $A\subseteq X$, consider the mapping $f:X\to \Bbb R$ that sends every element of $A$ to $1$ and every element of its complement to $0$. Then?

Comment: Might this proof even work for any set we map to with $\geq 2$ elements?

Comment: @GPerez It suffices there is some space with more than two points for which every mapping is continuous.

Comment: It might actually have to be $T_0$, I think.

Comment: For instance, $\{a,b\}$ and the coarse topology won't prove anything about $X$.

Comment: @GPerez You're correct. It suffices singleton sets are closed, for example.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I wanted to see if OP could be expanded easily, and it seems it could (also brushing up on my topology).